# HTML, JS, or php redirect just appends the destination to the current path

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user from a link to another domain.

ie: `mysite.com/xyz` sends the users to `www.google.com`. I am including a google analytics script, then trying to redirect, however all that is happening is the destination is appended to the current path and the page reloads. So I end up with: `mysite.com/www.google.com`

**Code (Tried all three):**

**JS:**

```
window.location = "www.google.com";
```

**PHP:**

```
header("Location: ".$link[0]['destination']);
```

**HTML:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;www.google.com">
```

All the the above just append `www.google.co` to the url. How can I redirect the page on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget `http://` or `https://`. Otherwise the browser or php engine think that you want to redirect to a specific file in the same server directory.

I advise you not to use javascript: it might be disabled in the client's browser.

You forgot a fourth way:

```
header('refresh: 3; url=http://www.google.com');
```

This redirects to Google after 3 seconds. I think it's more straightforward than a meta tag.